# Removing my previous company's OneDrive folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive

I have a OneDrive folder set up on my desktop from my previous employer.  I recently left that company and want to remove the folder, but can't see how to do that - googling shows how to remove OneDrive completely, but that's not what I want, just the 1 folder.

[image: Explorer view]

Comment: If you do not wish to remove One Drive, then you can delete the contents. That deletion syncs to the other (remote) folder. If that is not available, you will need to call the company and have them delete it. The other way is to back everything up to a neutral location, uninstall One Drive, restart, install it and set it up hopefully without the company folder.

Comment: Click on OneDrive icon in tray ->cog icon -> settings -> account. Are you connected with your company's account there? If so, did you try disconnecting it? Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the Notification Area of your desktop, there should be two onedrive icons (pic below).  I think you can click on the one from your company, go to settings, and, under account, select "Unlink this PC".

hope that helps,

Comment: No pic is attached here.